# SharePoint Access App Filter default list view

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

I am using SharePoint access App and I have bind the left filter with Title field. By default, the list shows all the data including blank title. I want to filter the default list to show data only when title has value. I do not want to create custom action, because I want to hide this data from User.

Is there a way we can filter this data?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

I created a query to filter records where title is not null and updated the default view to pick records from the query.

[image]

[image]